# where are power BI desktop data being stored: local on my laptop or in the cloud?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to test Power BI desktop (free). I want to test with some hospital data. But.... I can and will do this only, when all data are stored local.

For some reason I can't find a 100% answer to this question from Microsoft itself. Hopefully someone here knows the answer.

Many thanks! greetings Jan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where report data is stored depends on the [`Storage mode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-storage-mode). When it is `Import` the data is copied to the report file itself (`.pbix` file). When it is `DirectQuery`, it isn't copied. `Dual` is a combination of both, so there is a copy of the data in the report too.

While you are working with Power BI Desktop only, nothing is sent to the cloud at all. The fact that you can use it even without having a Power BI account speaks for itself.

Until you publish your report to the cloud (Power BI Service), the data stays in your network (or your computer, in case of local data source).

For more information about the [compliance of Power BI with HIPAA and other standards](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-added-to-microsoft-trust-center/), you can check the [Microsoft Trust Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/trust-center). But it is good to know, that there is also an on-premise version - [Power BI Report Server](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/report-server/), which you can use entirely in your network.

Comment: Suppose I publish a `Direct query` report (that connects to my local sql server) and an end user opens the dashboard, then will the data be stored in the cloud? And will it happen per report request or is there any cache?

Comment: There is a short lived cache in the cloud